# Ruby && operator on integers

Tags: ruby, operator-keyword

does anyone know the meaning of && and || when applied to integers in Ruby?

Here are some examples in IRB when && and || are applied to integers:

```
>> 1 && 2
=> 2

>> 2 && 1
=> 1

>> 15 && 20
=> 20

>> 20 && 15
=> 15

>> 0 && -1
=> -1

>> -1 && -2
=> -2

>> 1 || 2
=> 1

>> 2 || 1
=> 2
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 6):

The boolean operators `&&`, `||`, `and` and `or` are among the few that are not syntactic sugar for method calls, and thus, there are no different implementations in different classes.

In other words: they behave *exactly* the same for *all* objects, i.e. they behave the same for `Integer`s as they do for `String`s, `Hash`es, `Float`s, `Symbol`s, and any other object.

```
a && b
```

evaluates to `a` if `a` is falsey (and will not evaluate `b` at all in this case), otherwise it evaluates to `b` (and only then will `b` be evaluated)

```
a || b
```

evaluates to `a` if `a` is truthy (and will not evaluate `b` at all in this case), otherwise it evaluates to `b` (and only then will `b` be evaluated)

`nil` and `false` are falsey, everything else is truthy, including `0`, `0.0`, `''`, `[]`, and `{}`.

Comment: Thanks. I just realized I forgot to mention the short-circuiting behavior. (You weren't asking about it, but I added it in anyway.)